# Android Nougat, Runtime.exec won't work

Tags: java, android, shell, runtime

I'm trying to create a terminal emulator.
My code is

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/sh");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.directory(f);
p = builder.start();

stdOut = p.getInputStream();
stdIn = p.getOutputStream();

stdIn.write(("ls\n").getBytes());
stdIn.write(("echo EOF\n").getBytes());

while(true) {
    int n;
    try {
        n = stdOut.read();
    } catch (Exception | Error e) {
        return;
    }

    if(n == -1) continue;

    char c = (char) n;
    if(c == '\n') {
        if(line.equals("EOF")) break;
        else {
            if(write) outputable.onOutput(line);
            outputMsg[0] = outputMsg[0] + "\n" + line;
            line = "";
        }
    } else {
        line = line + c;
    }
}
```

This code **works** on Android 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0...
It doesn't work on Nougat (7.0).
No errors, no exceptions, nothing. It just hangs on this line:

```
n = stdOut.read();
```

[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).read() should hang only when there's nothing available in the stream.
Does someone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using Chainfire's library [libsuperuser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser).
Not a solution, but at least a workaround. And, one could also investigate the code, looking for a decisive difference, if he wants.

That's not my case, libsuperuser works like a charm.